# Is it possible to have value type based on the key on key/value pair in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

Let me give a simple example for better understanding of question

**Library holds:**

```
enum Keys
{
    [Description("Color select")]
    ColorSelection,

    [Description("Day select")]
    DaySelection,

    [Description("Gender select")]
    GenderSelection
}


enum Color
{
    [Description("White color")]
    White,

    [Description("Black color")]
    Black,

    [Description("Brown color")]
    Brown
}
enum Day
{
    [Description("Monday")]
    Monday,

    [Description("Tueday")]
    Tuesday,

    [Description("Wednesday")]
    Wednesday
}

enum Gender
{
    [Description("Male gender")]
    Male,

    [Description("Female gender")]
    Female            
}
```

**From Client I want like this:**

```
Dictionary<Keys, ??> values = new Dictionary<Keys, ??>();

values.Add(Keys.ColorSelection, <Auto suggest color>);
values.Add(Keys.DaySelection, <Auto suggest day>);
```

I'm okay to modify the library to have list of `values` as `Enum` but, I want the client to auto suggest the values with filters based on the key.

*Note:*
    1. I don't want Class(Model) with property as respective type since there are lot of keys available in the library and client will pick few and provide values.
    2. I cannot have values alone as `List<Values>` since some cases will have same `description` as value with different key..  Eg: "Yes/No values will be same with different keys"

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't understand your question... why don't you want to use a class? Having lots of keys doesn't stop you from using classes... You mean a Struct?

Comment: @Milney Say I have `Class` called `Detail` with 200 properties and from client I will assign 3 properties with value (Eg:  key, color gender) and rest(197) will be `null`.  I don't think it is the right way..

Comment: I would seriously re-think your design... 'Value types' will not help you avoid that problem... You can have a dictionary, with 3 keys added - the values for those 3 keys are your detail class.. no nulls involved

Comment: @Milney since the `Detail` class will have all the properties in it (all 200) and leave a way for client to have key/value `{Gender, Red}` added into dictionary and I don't want this to happen.  Correct me I misunderstood your solution somewhere

Comment: @Gopichandar What's wrong with 197 properties being null? Are you worried about performance? Memory consumption? Size of data being transferred across a network connection?

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your dictionary as:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<Keys, int>();
```

And then encapsulate this in your own custom class with a method that uses the Keys value of the key to interpret the value using the corresponding enum.

The whole problem here seems like a code smell though.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @owen-pauling; I think you should revise your current design. But based on the example you presented, here's one way you can handle this using `Dictionary<Keys, int>`:

```
Dictionary<Keys, int> values = new Dictionary<Keys, int>();
values.Add(Keys.ColorSelection, Convert.ToInt32(Color.Black));
values.Add(Keys.GenderSelection, Convert.ToInt32(Gender.Male));
values.Add(Keys.DaySelection, Convert.ToInt32(Day.Wednesday));

foreach (KeyValuePair<Keys, int> kv in values)
{
    dynamic enumValue = null;

    switch (kv.Key)
    {
        case Keys.ColorSelection:
            enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(Color), Convert.ToString(kv.Value));
            break;

        case Keys.DaySelection:
            enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(Day), Convert.ToString(kv.Value));
            break;

        case Keys.GenderSelection:
            enumValue = Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), Convert.ToString(kv.Value));
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Enum value: {0}", enumValue));
}

/* Output:
Enum value: Black
Enum value: Male
Enum value: Wednesday
*/
```

If you are open to making changes, maybe a class to hold the selections from the client will suffice. Here is an example with `List<DetailSelection>`:

```
public class DetailSelection
{
    public DetailSelection() { }

    public Type SelectionType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int EnumValue { get; set; }
}

List<DetailSelection> details = new List<DetailSelection>();
details.Add(new DetailSelection() {
    Description = "Color description",
    SelectionType = typeof(Color),
    EnumValue = Convert.ToInt32(Color.Black)
});
details.Add(new DetailSelection() {
    Description = "Day description",
    SelectionType = typeof(Day),
    EnumValue = Convert.ToInt32(Day.Wednesday)
});
details.Add(new DetailSelection() {
    Description = "Gender description",
    SelectionType = typeof(Gender),
    EnumValue = Convert.ToInt32(Gender.Male)
});

foreach (var detail in details)
{
    var enumValue = Enum.Parse(detail.SelectionType, Convert.ToString(detail.EnumValue));

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Enum value: {0}", enumValue));
}

/* Output:
Enum value: Black
Enum value: Wednesday
Enum value: Male
*/
```

In either case, I would probably try to take a step back and re-evaluate your design; just a friendly advice. :-)

I don't think you should use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` for this; since the **key** has to be unique, you will be constraining the client to only a single ColorSelection, GenderSelection, DaySelection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest (and probably best) solution is what Milney suggested in a comment:

```
class Properties
{
    Color? ColorSelection { get; set; }
    Day? DaySelection { get; set; }
    Gender? GenderSelection { get; set; }
}
```

Client code:

```
Properties values = new Properties();

values.ColorSelection = < Auto suggest color >;
values.DaySelection = < Auto suggest day >;
```

However, you seem concerned about having hundreds of properties where only a few of them would have values. This is probably a matter of *premature optimization*: it feels wasteful, but developer time is worth orders of magnitude more than any memory resources that this approach might cost. However, if that really bothers you, or if you determine through load testing that this is actually a problem, you can optimize your implementations without requiring any change to clients' code:

```
class Properties
{
    private Dictionary<Type, int> values = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
    Color? ColorSelection
    {
        get
        {
            return values.TryGetValue(typeof(Color), out int i)
                ? (Color?)i
                : null;
        }
        set
        {
            values[typeof(Color)] = (int)value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This leaves your API exactly the same, but stores all of the values in a dictionary just like you asked. You can also substitute `Type` for your `Keys` enum if you prefer. In fact, you could create a general-purpose "Add" method on your `Properties` class in case you want to allow client code to programmatically add values based on data known at runtime. But when clients want intellisense suggestions, they can use the properties instead.

If you go this route, I'd suggest using a T4 Template to generate your properties class so you're not writing massive amounts of boilerplate code.